# How to find Error Bounds of Trapezoidal Rule for semi-circle?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to answer a question:
How large should n be to guarantee the Trapezoidal Rule approximation for $\int_{-2.5}^{2.5}\sqrt{6.25-x^2}$ to be accurate to within 0.01 ?

I used $|E_T|<= \dfrac{{K(b−a)^3}}{12n^2}$

I got K = 0.4 (largest possible absolute value of the second derivative of the semi-circle function). Therefore, this was the overall formula I got: $|E_T|<= \dfrac{{0.4(5)^3}}{12n^2}$.

When I try to solve this question I get $n=21$. However $n$ actually is equal to 89. Is there something wrong I'm doing? I tried to ask around people and they don't understand what's happening. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you get for the second derivative? Remember you are not looking for the max of said function, rather the absolute value.

Comment: I just used symbolab to find the second derivative and graphed it to find the maximum of it. So I got K = 0.4